# How long does contract processing take?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I just uploaded my contact, bank and tax details to iTunes Connect; how long does this processing normally take? I can only find information from 5+ years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contract review process is about 20 minutes.